# I can't add data from my vue.js page to firestore database

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to vue.js and firebase

I want to add a collection to my `firebase/firestore` database from my Vue page

Here's my code:

```js
<script>
import db from '@/fb'
export default {
  methods: {
   addTask(){
      const project = {
        title: 'some title', 
        content:'some content',
        due:'01/01/2021', 
        person: 'someone',
        status:'ongoiing'

      }
      db.collection('projects').add(project).then(() =>  {
        console.log('added to database')
      })
      
   ...
```

and this is my firestore project configuration that I put in the 'fb.js' file on the 'src' folder:

```js
 //import firebase from 'firebase'
 import firebase from 'firebase/app'
 import 'firebase/firestore'
 // Your web app's Firebase configuration
 var firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "XXXXXX",
   authDomain: "XXXX.firebaseapp.com",
   projectId: "XXXXX",
   storageBucket: "XXXXX.appspot.com",
   messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXX",
   appId: "1:XXX:web:XXXXX"
 };
 // Initialize Firebase
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 const db = firebase.firestore();
 db.settings({timestampsInSnapshots:true})

 export default db;
```

My problem is when I click on the add button, nothing happens

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: can you add a catch callback method on the promise and print out the error object?

Comment: can you show me an example of how to write the carch callback (i'm new to this)

Comment: I added this to my code, but when i click on the add button, i have no error  
     db.collection('projects').add(project).then(() =>  {
        console.log('added!')
      }).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error writing : ", error);
});

Comment: Hi, without any error it will be difficult for us to help you. Can you maybe try to read an existing doc in Firestore? Do you have any specific Security Rules?